# cqlsh not able to locate cassandra running on localhost

Tags: cassandra

I want to use a cassandra instance without actually installing it on Ubuntu 15.10.
So, I extracted the tar file using the following command

tar -xvf apache-cassandra-3.6-bin.tar.gz

Then, inside the bin directory, I run the command as follows:

./cassandra

Then to confirm if cassandra is listening I run the following command:

netstat -an|grep 9042

And the port is listening.

Now, I run

./cqlsh

and I get the following error

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: try "telnet localhost 9042" does it connect?

Comment: Yes It is Connecting.

Comment: "./cqlsh localhost " ??

Comment: Doesnt work either. I was able to connect through the RazorSQL GUI. But I still need a CLI way of doing it.